# Add spring profile from command line

Tags: spring-boot

How can I *append* spring profiles from command lines, and not *replace* them?

When I use `--spring.profiles.active=prod` all profiles that are specified in yaml are *replaced* and not *added*.

I have the following yaml:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        include:
            - test
            - dev
```

So when I run it with `--spring.profiles.active=prod`, I would like to have all 3 profiles active: `prod,test,dev`.

How can I append profiles from command line?

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your profiles with comma this way:

```
--spring.profiles.active=prod,test,dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering by myself. I found that you can just specify an *included* profile, meaning that it will not override my profiles that I use in the app, but will just add one.

So I just added this command line parameter:

```
--spring.profiles.include=prod
```

and got all `dev,prod,test` profiles active during the app startup